# Is it possible to emit a cross-process signal or post a touch/mouse click event in Qt3.0?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, ipc

Is it possible to emit a signal or post a touch/mouse click event from one QT application to another application? The second QT application should just emit the event which makes the first QT application to consider as user input and process it.. is this possible? Please share your ideas..

Comment: Please change your question's title to reflect it's contents.

Comment: i could not understand why u said to change? can u make me clear..

Comment: First: QT is QuickTime, Qt - is a framework. Second: "touch/mouse" events are generated from OS callback, you can't "generate" them. But you can simulate them. There are @cmannett85 proposal to think about IPC first. It is very complex task and depends on your case. Your question is too abstract to get an answer. Show any attemps or what you have done already - and then ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to emit a signal or post a touch/mouse click event from
>   one QT application to another application?

Not directly.  You need to use [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), the most cross-platform compatible being sockets.

Comment: `QLocalSocket` will use prefferable platform backend :)

Comment: @DmitrySazonov That has only been available since Qt4.4.

Comment: Hi cmannett85, you mean the unix/linux sockets? or the Qt's sockets?

Comment: @ cmannett85 : from the libqte.a library i understood that the Qt process creates a socket with the touchscreen device and waits for data arrival.. do u mean to say the 2nd Qt application should post the event in this existing socket?

Comment: @ArunkumarRavi "you mean the unix/linux sockets? or the Qt's sockets?" Whichever you choose, Qt only provides wrapper classes for OS-level sockets.  As for your second comment, I have no idea what libqte.a is, you asked about sending data between two applications.